# MySQL - Update with counter based on subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm tring to make an update on a mysql table:

```
 PrimaryId | SecondaryId | Order
-----------+-------------+-------
     1     |      1      |   0
     2     |      1      |   0
     3     |      2      |   0
     4     |      3      |   0
     5     |      3      |   0
     6     |      3      |   0
```

to:

```
 PrimaryId | SecondaryId | Order
-----------+-------------+-------
     1     |      1      |   1
     2     |      1      |   2
     3     |      2      |   1
     4     |      3      |   1
     5     |      3      |   2
     6     |      3      |   3
```

on rows that have the same secondary id and an Order of 0.
so far i tried to select the values to update in an subquery, and update the rows with max()+1

...sadly, this won't work since the select is not allowed to work on the same table as the update. is there a way to do that?

Comment: you want to do it in one SQL Request?

Comment: Well, i'll do it with a (PHP) script, if i won't be able to do it with an sql statement. i suck at sql...

Comment: @GuilhemHoffmann: if it's possible, yes...

Comment: you can't create a temporary table to store the intermediate result ?

Comment: well, that would probably be more work than just set up a php script

Comment: please, could you give us the query you tried to compute order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
JOIN (
   SELECT `PrimaryId`,
          `SecondaryId`,
          (SELECT count(*)
           FROM Table1 t1
           WHERE t1.`SecondaryId` = t.`SecondaryId`
            AND t1.`PrimaryId` <= t.`PrimaryId`
           ) `Order`
   FROM Table1 t
) t2
ON t1.`PrimaryId` = t2.`PrimaryId`
SET t1.`Order` = t2.`Order`
;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f2102/1

Comment: nice, you saved a lot of time for me :)