# Count in MS Access without "groupby"

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access as shown beneath. I want the count of records having same data in the table as in column "ID" and column "Date" and column "Admit" against each record.
In excel I used "countifs".
Since I need all the rows as it is hence cannot use "groupby" in access.
The desired result is shown in columns "count - admit" and "count - refund"

```
Name    ID  Date        Admit/  Fees/      Count - Admit      Count - Refund
                               Refund   

ABC     11  11/11/2013  Admit   100         2                   1
BCD     12  11/11/2013  Admit   150         2                   0
CDE     13  12/11/2013  Admit   200         1                   1
DEF     14  13/11/2013  Admit   150         1                   0
ABC     11  11/11/2013  Refund  -100        2                   1
CDE     13  12/11/2013  Refund  -200        1                   1
ABC     11  11/11/2013  Admit   100         2                   1
BCD     12  11/11/2013  Admit   150         2                   0
```

Comment: could you clarify your data source and target please

Comment: @ guilhem : the data source and the targets are the same table. The results of count needs to be added as a column in the same table

Comment: is it for mysql or for access ? (blank in column name would be an issue in mysql)

Comment: @guilhem : It is in access. However, if required can edit the column name

Answer (score 2):

In Access, for test data in a table named [AdmitRefund]

```
Name  ID  Date        Admit_Refund  Fees  Count_Admit  Count_Refund
----  --  ----------  ------------  ----  -----------  ------------
ABC   11  2013-11-11  Admit          100                           
BCD   12  2013-11-11  Admit          150                           
CDE   13  2013-11-12  Admit          200                           
DEF   14  2013-11-13  Admit          150                           
ABC   11  2013-11-11  Refund        -100                           
CDE   13  2013-11-12  Refund        -200                           
ABC   11  2013-11-11  Admit          100                           
BCD   12  2013-11-11  Admit          150
```

the following query

```sql
UPDATE AdmitRefund SET
    Count_Admit = DCount("*", "AdmitRefund", "[ID]=" & [ID] & " AND [Date]=#" & Format([Date], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND [Admit_Refund]=""Admit"""), 
    Count_Refund = DCount("*", "AdmitRefund", "[ID]=" & [ID] & " AND [Date]=#" & Format([Date], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND [Admit_Refund]=""Refund""")
```

populates the columns like this

```
Name  ID  Date        Admit_Refund  Fees  Count_Admit  Count_Refund
----  --  ----------  ------------  ----  -----------  ------------
ABC   11  2013-11-11  Admit          100            2             1
BCD   12  2013-11-11  Admit          150            2             0
CDE   13  2013-11-12  Admit          200            1             1
DEF   14  2013-11-13  Admit          150            1             0
ABC   11  2013-11-11  Refund        -100            2             1
CDE   13  2013-11-12  Refund        -200            1             1
ABC   11  2013-11-11  Admit          100            2             1
BCD   12  2013-11-11  Admit          150            2             0
```

**Edit re: comment**

The above query assumed that [ID] was numeric. For [ID] as text, use:

```sql
UPDATE AdmitRefund SET
    Count_Admit = DCount("*", "AdmitRefund", "[ID]='" & [ID] & "' AND [Date]=#" & Format([Date], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND [Admit_Refund]=""Admit"""), 
    Count_Refund = DCount("*", "AdmitRefund", "[ID]='" & [ID] & "' AND [Date]=#" & Format([Date], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND [Admit_Refund]=""Refund""")
```

Comment: @ Gord : Thanks for the solution. It seems to be working. But the problem is, on running the query, Access gives an error message - "Access didn't update the fields due to a type conversion failure"

Comment: @user3041352 Edit your question to specify what the field types are. Or, if possible, make a copy of the database with the table in it (you can delete the data rows if you wish), upload the database to [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com), and then post the link here so we can take a look at it.

Comment: The data types of the fields are as under; ID - Text, Date - Date/Time, Admit_Refund - Text, Count_Admit - Number, Count_Refund - Number

Comment: @ Gord : Is there any wayout? or any possible solution?

Comment: @ Gord : Same result Gord. Same error even with updated query.

Comment: @Nirav A working example is available [here](http://wikisend.com/download/294336/admit.zip). Compare it to your implementation to see what is different.

Answer (score 1):

```
      UPDATE Table1 t1
      JOIN (
         SELECT `name`,
                  `id`,
                  `date`,
                  `admit`,
                  (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM Table1 t1
                   WHERE t1.`Name` = t.`Name`
                   AND  t1.`ID` = t.`ID`
                   AND  t1.`Date` = t.`Date`
                   AND  t1.`Admit` = t.`Admit`
                   ) `CAdmit`
         FROM Table1 t
      ) t2
      ON t1.`Name` = t2.`Name`
      SET t1.`CAdmit` = t2.`CAdmit`
       WHERE     t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`
                   AND  t1.`Date` = t2.`Date`
                   AND  t1.`Admit` = t2.`Admit`
      ;
```

[Working fiddle sample here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/950c8/1)

You can have a look on that also
 [MySQL - Update with counter based on subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222520/mysql-update-with-counter-based-on-subquery?noredirect=1#comment30156454_20222520)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the pattern, but you will still need a group by, but it would be two parts...  First, you need your query by ID so you can apply the counts to the original records.  This is all assuming your table is based on just the first 5 columns provided in your original post.

```
select
      YT.Name,
      YT.ID,
      YT.Date,
      YT.AdmitRefund,
      YT.Fees,
      PQ.AdmitCount,
      PQ.RefundCount
   from
      YourTable YT
         JOIN ( select YT2.ID
                       SUM( IIF( YT2.AdmitRefund = 'Admit', 1, 0 )) AdmitCount,
                       SUM( IIF( YT2.AdmitRefund = 'Refund', 1, 0 )) RefundCount
                   from
                      YourTable YT2
                   group by
                      YT2.ID ) PQ
           ON YT.ID = PQ.ID
```

The inner PreQuery gets your counts per ID, then that is re-joined back to the original raw data so each instance of original row has the total respective admit vs refund counts.